# A framework for multi-valued categorical attributes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data

In the scenario in which I'm working each entity could be represented in terms of **N** distinct properties that I will call *p1*, *p2*, ..., *pn*.
For each of them, an entity, can have its specific range of values for a single property.
An entity's property couldn't have any value associated to it.

Formally speaking, given an entity *e* and calling *pk* a specific property associated to *e*, it can have *nk* values associated (*nk* >= 0).

This is a brief example:

```
<entity 1>
director: Tarantino
distributor: Miramax
producer: Bender
starring: Fox, Hannah, Dreyfus, Thurman

<entity 2>
director: Tarantino
distributor: Miramax
producer: Bender
starring: Travolta, Jackson, Thurman
```

I'm not able to understand how to represent these entities in order to be used by a machine learning algorithm. I have seen some others that transform multi-valued categorical attributes in multiple binary attributes. I think that in this case is fundamental to analyze each property exactly as it is, with all its values.

After the creation of this method, I will be able to represent all the entities in my dataset. 
Supposing that, in this scenario, there are users that express a preference towards some of the entities (only a binary preference e.g., Tom likes *entity 1* and so on). Using a machine learning algorithm, I would like to generate a model for each user in order to be able to understand if a new entity (a new film) could or not be liked by that user (this can be expressed with a value in a range between 0-1).

At this point I have two distinct questions that I will report here:

1. What could be a proper way to represent the dataset entities?
2. What could be a proper machine learning algorithm which is able to generate a model using the entities that I have?

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot represent the entities? You _did_ give an example representation. So the question is how to represent it in as SQL data, or how to tabularize it (like with co-called [dummy variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29))?

Comment: I've edited my question. What I don't know is which is the proper way in order to use this data in a machine learning algorithm.

Comment: Do you have any machine learning algorithm in mind? (There are many, some have special restrictions.)

Comment: Unfortunately not and this is due to the fact that I have multi-valued categorical attribute. I haven't find any algorithm which works in this situation. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most standard way of dealing with variables having an array of values is using [dummy variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29), i.e. creating a column for each possibility and assigning `0` and `1` depending if a n attribute is absent or present, respectively.

See for example [how to do it in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889588/create-dummies-from-column-with-multiple-values-in-pandas) (if you are using Python) and [Generate a dummy-variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable-in-r).

The **good** thing is that you can treat `0` and `1` as categorical (e.g. for decision trees or random forests) or numerical (for various regressions, k-nearest neighbors, principal component analysis, k-mean, etc). Sometimes you need to convert all variables to numerical, even if there is only a single attribute per entry.

The **bad** thing is that if there are many options, either you need to restrict yourself to only the most common or perform some dimensional reduction with the principal component analysis.

The **ugly** thing is that even if you are using categorical-only variables, then you typically present single-valued variables with text/id, while multi-valued with dummy variables.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. Could you please provide to me a simple ARFF representation of the entities? I ask to you this simply to have a good reference from which I can start my work.

Comment: What is "ARFF"?

Comment: The dataset file format that is used in the Weka library

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia I am not using Weka, so I have no idea. But did you try googling `Weka dummy variables`?

Comment: The dummy coding only works for independent variables, how about multi-level categorical dependent variables?